# Recovering MySQL Database From Data Directories

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, lamp

I am trying to recover a MySQL database from data directories. I do have a backup, but it is a week old and I would prefer not to use it.

I have transferred all of the files to a fresh MySQL installation and have given them 777 permissions along with directory and group ownership to mysql.

When I try to start, I get the following two errors:

InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 0 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!

and

170110 16:42:58 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
170110 16:42:58 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

For the first error, I have tried specifying the log file size in the my.cnf and also as an argument to mysqld. I keep getting the same error message.

For the second error, I have tried deleting the ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1, but if I do, I get a bunch of nonsensical characters when starting mysqld followed by

/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x286668)[0x7f65298d4668]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.

How can I retrieve the data in this database?

Comment: Have you copied `ib_logfile0` as well?

Comment: Yes, that file has been present, although I have tried deleting it. I get errors regardless of whether the file is present or not.